# keycloak docker compose behing nginx question

Tags: docker, nginx, keycloak

I have setup in docker-compose mysql, keycloack and nginx.
Changed in standalone and standalone-ha

```
<web-context>keycloak/auth</web-context>
```

so I can use keycloak under /keycloak.
If I expose 8080 keycloack port I can use it under http://localhost:8080/keycloak/auth/.
Login, changing settings etc all works fine.

So I can assume that this keycloak configuration is fine.
But I want to hide it under nginx proxy.

here is my nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  text/html;

    server {
        listen 8080;

        location /keycloak {
            proxy_pass          http://keycloak:8080/keycloak/auth/;
            proxy_set_header    Host               $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port   $server_port;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        }

    }
}
```

if i go to http://localhost/keycloak or http://localhost/keycloak/auth
I see an 404 Nginx error.

I can not find this problem..

any idea how to solve this ?
thanks!

EDIT:
when i set proxy_pass          http://keycloak:8080;
then url: http://localhost/keycloak/auth/ works fine,
but I wonder why if I go to http://localhost/keycloak/ I am redirected to the http://localhost/auth
any ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried to rewrite your url from /keycloak to /keycloak/auth ? https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

Comment: not yet, good hint thanks!

Comment: Does rewrite helped?